# MYSQL Reservation search, query on each day between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to consolidate this into a single query.

The reservation system has 2 tables, hotels and reservations.

```
hotels(id, num_rooms)
reservations(hotel_id, start_date, end_date) (each reservation is for 1 room)
```

I need to perform a query where the user says they need x rooms between date1 and date2, and the system returns all hotels that have enough rooms (while calculating all of the reservations each day to determine the rooms available) for the entirety of the dates.

My experimentations have been a total mess, as I can't think how to group these sub results together to make some progress. I know I'm going to have to use a few subqueries to get this going, I just can't wrap my head around it properly.

```
   -- a poor snippet to try and get some foothold
   SELECT h.* from hotels as h 
   left join reservations as r on r.hotel_id=h.id 
   where 
   --(select count(*) from reservations where start date between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-31' group by hotel_id)
```

Comment: Post sample data and the desired result.

Comment: `num_rooms` in hotels is the number of rooms that the hotel has?

Comment: Fun challenge, +1 for that.

Comment: @JorgeCampos yes, that's the capacity of the hotel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution generates the range of dates for all reservations and counts the number of reservations for each hotel and date. Using this information the query then checks that the total number of rooms minus the maximum reservations for any day in the requested period is equal to or above the requested number of rooms.

I used a derived table to help that generate the date range, but that could easily be replaced by a numbers table.

My script (I used variables for the query limits):

```
set @start_date := '2015-04-01'; 
set @end_date   := '2015-04-04'; 
set @num_rooms  := 1;

SELECT 
    id AS hotel_id
FROM
    hotels h
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        hotel_id, date, COUNT(*) reserved
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        r.hotel_id, a.date, r.start_date, r.end_date
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        CAST(@start_date + INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY
                AS DATETIME) AS Date
    FROM
        (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c) a
    INNER JOIN reservations r ON a.Date >= @start_date
        AND a.Date <= @end_date
    LEFT JOIN hotels h ON h.id = r.hotel_id) reservations
    WHERE
        date >= start_date AND date <= end_date
    GROUP BY hotel_id , date) a ON a.hotel_id = h.id
GROUP BY hotel_id , num_rooms
HAVING (num_rooms - MAX(reserved)) >= @num_rooms
    OR hotel_id IS NULL
```

My test data:

```
create table hotels (id int, num_rooms int);
insert hotels values (1, 3),(2, 5), (3, 20);
create table reservations (hotel_id int, start_date date, end_date date);
insert reservations (hotel_id, start_date, end_date) values
(1, '2015-03-01', '2015-03-05'),
(1, '2015-03-01', '2015-03-02'),
(1, '2015-03-01', '2015-03-05'),

(2, '2015-03-01', '2015-03-05'),
(2, '2015-03-01', '2015-03-05'),
(2, '2015-03-01', '2015-03-05'),
(2, '2015-03-02', '2015-03-05'),

(3, '2015-03-01', '2015-03-05'),
(3, '2015-03-02', '2015-03-05'),
(3, '2015-03-03', '2015-03-05'),
(3, '2015-03-04', '2015-03-06');
```

With the test data above the query would return hotels 2 and 3.

Comment: I tried this with 
`set @start_date := '2015-03-03'; 
set @end_date   := '2015-03-04'; 
set @num_rooms  := 1; `but hotel 1 doesn't appear. Is there a way to adjust for those dates?

Comment: @Ryan Ah yes, I see. I wrote the code for MSSQL (for which it works) but I must have made some mistake when I rewrote it for MySQL. I'll try to find the error.

Comment: @Ryan The union/cross join creates a sequence of numbers (0-999), see this example which might be clearer: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/864 I think it should work for timestamps too, if not you can cast the timestamp to a datetime.

Comment: I tried to implement and when reservations has 0 rows, 0 rows are returned. Also if I change the search dates to a time without any reservations, 0 results are returned.

Comment: @Ryan I found some errors and made some further changes and hope that it works now.